# How to remove &amp; from an XML file using java?

Tags: java, xml, excel

I am reading the input Excel file and in that i have 1 fields for the address.In that field the special character is coming which is (&).While i am going to parse this character (&) and trying to write it to the XML file at that time the character converts into the (&amp).

I want to remove the translated character (&amp) from the XML file and wants that it must remain as it was read from the Excel file and writtern as the (&) in the XML file.
**WWW.GEVERS&** converted to **WWW.GEVERS&amp**
if any body has any solution or any other code snippet,which would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Mishal Shah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data contains an ampersand -- which apparently it does -- then that ampersand has to be escaped as &amp; if you put it in a text node in your XML document.

So it sounds like your XML software is behaving correctly. Why do you think you have to do anything about this? I don't think you do.

Comment: +1: An ampersand (&) must be escaped and turned into the equivalent character entity reference (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference), which is &amp;  If you don't do this, the XML file will fail to parse when an XML-aware program tries to read it.

Answer (score 1):

@Mishal, see Paul's answer.  If you replace the `&amp;` with a `&`, you no longer have a "well-formed" XML document.  You would actually be introducing a syntax error.

So you just need to read or view your XML document with a program that knows how to render XML, such as Internet Explorer (just make sure your file suffix is .xml).

Answer (score 0):

Since it will not be a valid xml file anymore, you should handle it as raw text and do a raw replace of &amp; -> &

By the way, why don't you want to keep it valid xml ?